# How to eager load a custom made relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have a `statuses` table where i store my statuses for multiple models(tables). for ex:

```
comments
id | status | text    | ... 
---------------------------
1  | 2      | great.. |
2  | 3      | thats.. |

posts
id | status | body | ...
---------------------------
1  | 4      | hey..| 
2  | 5      | i w..|

statuses
id | type    | title     | ...
---------------------------
1  | comment | succes    |
2  | comment | error     | 
3  | comment | published |
4  | post    | deleted   |
5  | post    | pending   |
```

Here i am able with belongsTo relations access the corresponding record.

```
class Post extends Model {
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, ....);
    }
}
```

But what i want is to eager load the status options for comments so that i can drop down or something like that. I can create a custom relationship with where but that does not eager load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `with` with your main model and can load data of relations. Like `Post::with('status')`. Ref [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) for this.

**Status model**

```php
class Status extends Model
{
    public static $COMMENT_STATUS = 'comment';
    public static $POST_STATUS = 'post';

    public function scopeForComments($query)
    {
        return $query->where('type', self::$COMMENT_STATUS);
    }

    public function scopeForPosts($query)
    {
        return $query->where('type', self::$POST_STATUS);
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller:

**MyController.php**

```php
Status::forComments()->get(); //List up all the statuses for comments
Status::forArticles()->get(); //List up all the statuses for articles
```

Comment: actually i am lookin for calling the statuses of a model (the statuses of comment). So according to my tables what kind of relationship do i need for `Post::with('status')->get();`. when i call the relation it has to get the records where the type is `comment` from the statuses table.

Comment: i have no problem gettin the current status of that model. But i need to call all the possible statuses of comment (deleted, pending in this case)

Comment: i can use  public function `statuses()
 {
  return Status::where('type', self::class);
 }` method to call all the statuses of that model but i can't eager load

Comment: I guess i need some kind of a polymorphic relationship where i can compare the table value with the model name. in my case, get all records where type is `App\Comment`

Comment: In your update how do you get all statuses of comment model (success, error, published).

Comment: besides with `$this->belongsTo` i get only the status where is specified in posts tables status column. for ex if it is 2 i will only get a single record, error which where `->where('type', 'comment');` wont help much. Am i wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do? Something like `Status::forComments()->all();`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192030/discussion-between-skeletor-and-p-ellul).